# How to access run-time request.session values in forms.py definition?

Tags: django

I have an inventory management app that will be serving multiple locations (called contexts in my app). When a user is logged in, their current context is stored as a value in request.sessions.

I would like users to only be able to browse and retrieve records for their own location.

I've been trying to this by filtering the queryset that is called in the form definition to populate the select dropdown, i.e.

```
    referenced_catalog = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Inventory_unit_catalog.objects.all().filter(parent_business_unit_context_id=user_context_id),
```

I've tried implementing several different (but similar) approaches from various SO posts, that involve defining an init block to the form, such as:

```
class InventoryStockAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_context_id = kwargs.pop('user_context_id', None)
        super(InventoryStockAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=96,widget=forms.TextInput(),required=True)

    referenced_catalog = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = Inventory_unit_catalog.objects.all().filter(parent_business_unit_context_id=self.user_context_id),
        label = u"",
        widget = ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Inventory_unit_catalog,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Select catalog...', 'data-width': '35em'},
        required=False))

    class Meta():
        model = Inventory_unit_stock
        fields = ('name',)
```

(Different SO answers had one way or the other.)

Then in views.py:

```
user_context_id = request.session.get('user_context_id')
...
add_form = InventoryStockAddForm(user_context_id=user_context_id)
```

I've even tried using the SessionStore per https://djangobook.com/using-sessions-views-2/:

```
SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore
s = SessionStore()
user_context_id = s['user_context_id']
```

but it always fails at the moment the forms.py is updated as Django validates the code and cannot find a key value at the moment of validation.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @Alasdair updated, per your request.

Comment: Please check the indentation

Comment: @Alasdair, corrected, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access `self.user_context_id` inside `referenced_catalog = forms.ModelChoiceField(...)` - that code runs when the module is loaded, not when the form is initialised.

Instead, you should set the queryset inside the `__init__` method.

```
class InventoryStockAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_context_id = kwargs.pop('user_context_id', None)
        super(InventoryStockAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['referenced_catalog'].queryset = Inventory_unit_catalog.objects.all().filter(parent_business_unit_context_id=self.user_context_id)

    referenced_catalog = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = Inventory_unit_catalog.objects.none(),
        label = u"",
        widget = ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Inventory_unit_catalog,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Select catalog...', 'data-width': '35em'},
        required=False))
```

Comment: Thanks! Though to clarify, I had to move the entire referenced_catalog field definition inside the init, otherwise the definition wouldn't be able to access the queryset, for the same reasons as you highlighted. Awesome!

Comment: No, you shouldn’t need to move the entire field definition into `__init__`. The field definition uses an empty queryset using `.none()`. Then you can override the queryset in `__init__`, where you have access to `self.user_context_id`.

Comment: You're right, my mistake - I read your solution and went to implement it without looking closely enough at your posted code changes. If you do your way, it works beautifully! If you move the entire definition in, the other aspects of the field (it's a django-select2 field) don't initialize properly.

Comment: I don’t see how initialising the field in `__init__` would break select2, but glad the code above worked for you.

Comment: thanks again for your kind help. In the end, your corrections answered my specific issue (getting the variable "down" to where the queryset could access it). However, it's proven futile as the querysets seem to be ignored – whether .all(), .none() or anything else, the delivered results are always all the items. More information at [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575382/queryset-for-django-select2-widget-being-ignored)