# Queryset for django-select2 widget being ignored

Tags: django, django-forms

In my project I am using Django-Select2 heavily, particularly its ModelSelect2Widget as my users frequently need to select from lists of 2,000-6,000 items. In all my uses of it up 'til now, the queryset for the widget has always been called as ".all()" instances of a model, for the user to select from, and there's been no issues.

Now, however, I have implementations in different parts of the project for which filtering the queryset of options for the widget is necessary. In all of these cases, however, any modification of the queryset seems to have no effect, and I'm wondering if there is a problem with the widget itself.

In the primary case, the items in the database are boolean-flagged as active/inactive (about 65% inactive), and I need to only have active items available for the end-user to select.

I'm able to filter the queries correctly via the shell.

In the form definitiion, any filtering (".filter(flag_active=True)", or even setting the queryset to ".none()" has no effect – there is no apparent change in the options in the dropdown/autocomplete. Being that it is a select2 input, I can only view a small number of items at a time, but both the initial retrieved population and the winnowed-down selection as I type indicate that the filters are not been followed.

```
MODEL:

class Inventory_product_base(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,null=False)
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=96,null=True,blank=True)
    name = models.CharField('Item name',max_length=96,null=False)
    flag_active = models.BooleanField("Active item",default=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True)
    unit_of_measure = models.CharField('UOM',max_length=24, choices=UNITS_OF_MEASURE,default='EACH')
    spec = models.CharField(max_length=36,null=True,blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Inventory_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='cat_products')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory_subcategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='subcat_products')
    note = models.CharField(max_length=275,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

FORM:

class InventoryCatalogUpdateProductsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    parent_product_base = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Inventory_product_base.objects.filter(flag_active=True),
        label=u"",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Inventory_product_base,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Select product...', 'data-width': '100%'},),)

    class Meta():
        model = Inventory_unit_catalog
        fields = ('parent_product_base',)


class InventoryCatalogUpdateAllProductsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    parent_product_base = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Inventory_product_base.objects.all(),
        label=u"",
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Inventory_product_base,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Select product...', 'data-width': '100%'},),)

    class Meta():
        model = Inventory_unit_catalog
        fields = ('parent_product_base',)

InventoryCatalogUpdateProductsFormset = modelformset_factory(model=Inventory_unit_catalog,form=InventoryCatalogUpdateProductsForm,extra=10,can_delete=True)

InventoryCatalogUpdateAllProductsFormset = modelformset_factory(model=Inventory_unit_catalog,form=InventoryCatalogUpdateAllProductsForm,extra=10,can_delete=True)

VIEW:
if product_flag == 'active':
    formset = InventoryCatalogUpdateProductsFormset(queryset=parent_unit_catalog.products.filter(flag_active=True))
else:
    formset = InventoryCatalogUpdateAllProductsFormset(queryset=parent_unit_catalog.products.all())
```

As noted, if I change the above queryset to .none() (or anything else, either in the widget or in the view) there is no difference in the rendered choices in the select2 field.

I've tried separate, parallel forms and formsets. Originally I tried for a more sophisticated approach, to pass a parameter and have the different querysets selected within a single form, by adding the following:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.product_flag = kwargs.pop('product_flag')
    super(InventoryCatalogAddToForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print("__init__ has product_flag: ",self.product_flag)
    if self.product_flag == 'active':
        self.fields['parent_product_base'].queryset = Inventory_product_base.objects.filter(flag_active=True)
        print("Screened for flag_active=True")
    else:
        self.fields['parent_product_base'].queryset = Inventory_product_base.objects.all()
        print("Screened for flag_active=False")
```

and I was able to verify by the debug prints that the correct filter choices were executing, but without any effect. So I moved back to a simpler, more direct approach of separate forms, and still nothing.

Any advice would be welcome. My project is several months in and Django-Select2 is one of the foundations across it, I would hate to learn that it cannot filter the select2 input and I would need to find a replacement.

Comment: Have you tried creating the widget via the shell and checking it's queryset attribute/get_queryset method? If those check out to be filtered correctly, the problem could be with the select2 `AutoResponseView`. Also: `self.fields['parent_product_base'].queryset` sets the queryset for the formfield (i.e. allowed choices for validation), use `self.fields[foo].widget.queryset` to set the widget's choices.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform Thank you - I hadn't realized you could specify two different querysets (one for validation, one for widget), I assumed the single set served both purposes. Filtering on the `.widget.queryset` made all the difference! Please repost your comment as an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: yay internet points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.fields['parent_product_base'].queryset` sets the queryset for the formfield (i.e. allowed choices for validation).

Use `self.fields['parent_product_base'].widget.queryset` to set the widget's choices.